# Complex Number Conjugate proofs: why aren't the sides equal in the difference equation

Tags: complex-numbers

Regarding this complex number conjugate proof. Why aren't the two sides equal.

Adding the link where I found this proof.
[Properties of Conjugate Number](https://physicscatalyst.com/maths/complex-conjugate-numbers.php)

[complex conjugate formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFYdO.png)

Comment: They are equal: both have $a-c$. Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: For real $a,b,c,d$, instead $$\overline{a-c+i(b-d)} = a-c-i(b-d)$$.

Comment: For real $a,b,c,d$, instead $$a-c+\overline i(b-d) = a-c-i(b-d)$$.

Comment: The formatting pictured is pretty bad, I would not trust that the person who made the image tried very hard.  It appears at a glance that there is simply a typo that turned the $-c$ into a $+c$ on accident as we get to your first highlighted section, however it is difficult to tell exactly since there are surely several examples of overlines which should be extending over large sections of numbers which incorrectly appear only over a single element.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo. In both cases, the result should come out to $a - c - i(b - d).$